# Error in terminal when trying to run code in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm relatively new to using IDEs and recently started using VSCode for class. I'm using the Code Runner extension and working on a Mac. Whenever I go to run a piece of code I receive the following message in my terminal:

> The default interactive shell is now zsh.
> To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
> For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

Could someone help explain what exactly this message means? I think for class we want to use the Bash shell so I'm hesitant to make any changes to the current settings but I don't want it to interfere with my ability to run/test code.

Comment: What don't you understand about the message that isn't explained by the document it links to?

Comment: It shouldn't make too much of a difference I believe, but if you specifically need to use bash, you can go ahead and change it.